# Codeigniter Validation failed when i submit google analytics code

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

when i submit analytics code from form .validation failed this condition returns false

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
```

but when i enter something else then analytics code above condition retuns true and record updated successfully .even if if left it blank it works fine .i checked might be its token issue .in configuration file i have set  to false it still dont work, it submits data and woks fine below is my ajax request code and controller code .

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

but the wired thing same code works on other servers .

```
 var csrfName="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>";

   var csrfHash="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>";
$(document).ready(function(){
    CKEDITOR.replace('siteDescription',{allowedContent:true});
    $('#siteTags').tagsInput();
});
$(document).on('click','#updateBasic',function(e){  
$('#successSettings').addClass('hide').html('');
        $('#errorSettings').addClass('hide').html('');
        var description=CKEDITOR.instances.siteDescription.getData();
        var googleAnalyticsCode=$('#googleAnalyticsCode').val();
        var fbAppId=$('#fbAppId').val();
        var fbAppSecet=$('#fbAppSecet').val();
        var googleAppId=$('#googleAppId').val();
        var googleAppSecret=$('#googleAppSecret').val();
        var siteTags=$('#siteTags').val();
        var siteName=$('#siteName').val();
        var fb=$('#fb').val();
        var tw=$('#tw').val();
        var db=$('#db').val();
        var gp=$('#gp').val();
        var smtpUsername=$('#smtpUsername').val();
        var smtpPassword=$('#smtpPassword').val();
      var imgurClientId=$('#imgurClientId').val();

        var adminApproveQuestions=$('#adminApproveQuestions').is(":checked")?1:0;


        var fd = new FormData(); 
        fd.append('googleAnalyticsCode',googleAnalyticsCode);
        fd.append('fbAppId',fbAppId);
        fd.append('fbAppSecet',fbAppSecet);
        fd.append('googleAppId',googleAppId);
        fd.append('googleAppSecret',googleAppSecret);
        fd.append('description',description);
        fd.append('siteTags',siteTags);
        fd.append('siteName',siteName);
        fd.append('smtpUsername',smtpUsername);
        fd.append('smtpPassword',smtpPassword);
        fd.append('imgurClientId',imgurClientId);
        fd.append('adminApproveQuestions',adminApproveQuestions);  
        //fd.append('adminApproveAnswers',adminApproveAnswers);  
        fd.append('fb',fb);
        fd.append('tw',tw);
        fd.append('db',db);
        fd.append('gp',gp);
        fd.append(csrfName,csrfHash);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'<?php echo base_url()."post-update-settings"?>',
            type: "POST",
            data : fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(response) 
            {
                var response=$.parseJSON(response);
                if(response['type']==1)
                {
                    $('#successSettings').html(response['html']);
                    $('#successSettings').removeClass('hide');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#errorSettings').html(response['html']);
                    $('#errorSettings').removeClass('hide');
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, data, error) {
                if (window.confirm("This page is expired , Please click Yes to reload the page"))
                {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

controller code

```
public function postUpdateSiteSettings()
    {
        if (!checksessionAdmin()) {
            responseGenerate(2,"Please login to continue");
        }
        $fb=secureInput($this->input->post('fb'));
        $gp=secureInput($this->input->post('gp'));
        $db=secureInput($this->input->post('db'));
        $tw=secureInput($this->input->post('tw'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('siteName', 'Site Name', 'required|max_length[100]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('siteTags', 'Site Tags', 'max_length[100]');

        if (strlen($fb)>0)
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fb', 'Facebook social link', 'max_length[200]|callback_valid_url');
        if (strlen($gp)>0)
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('gp', 'Google plus social link', 'max_length[200]|callback_valid_url');
        if (strlen($db)>0)
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('db', 'Dribble social link', 'max_length[200]|callback_valid_url');
        if (strlen($tw)>0)
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tw', 'Twitter social link', 'max_length[200]|callback_valid_url');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('smtpUsername', 'SMTP Username', 'max_length[200]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('smtpPassword', 'SMTP Password', 'max_length[200]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
            $siteName=secureInput($this->input->post('siteName'));
            $siteTags=secureInput($this->input->post('siteTags'));
            $adminApproveQuestions=secureInput($this->input->post('adminApproveQuestions'));



            $googleAnalyticsCode=(trim($this->input->post('googleAnalyticsCode')));
            $fbAppId=secureInput($this->input->post('fbAppId'));
            $fbAppSecet=secureInput($this->input->post('fbAppSecet'));
            $googleAppId=secureInput($this->input->post('googleAppId'));
            $googleAppSecret=secureInput($this->input->post('googleAppSecret'));
            $description=encodeContent(trim($this->input->post('description')));
            $smtpUsername=secureInput($this->input->post('smtpUsername'));
            $smtpPassword=secureInput($this->input->post('smtpPassword'));
            $imgurClientId=secureInput($this->input->post('imgurClientId'));
            $this->App_model->updateData('siteSettings',['smtpUsername'=>$smtpUsername,'smtpPassword'=>$smtpPassword,'imgurClientId'=>$imgurClientId,'adminApproveQuestions'=>$adminApproveQuestions, 'googleAnalyticsCode'=>$googleAnalyticsCode,'fbAppId'=>$fbAppId,'fbAppSecet'=>$fbAppSecet,'googleAppId'=>$googleAppId,'googleAppSecret'=>$googleAppSecret,'facebookLink'=>$fb,'googleLink'=>$gp,'twitterLink'=>$db,'dribbleLink'=>$tw,'siteName'=>$siteName,'tags'=>$siteTags,'description'=>$description]);
            responseGenerate(1,"Site settings was successfully updated");
        } else {
            responseGenerate(0,validation_errors('<p>','</p>'));
        }
    }
```